# Can a ritual caster learn weapon bond

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, class-feature, warlock, rituals

I couldn't find an answer to my during a search so I thought I would pose it here. While peering through the eldritch knight subclass I read the following description for weapon bond (emphasis mine):

> At 3rd level, you learn a **ritual** that creates a **magical** bond
>   between yourself and one weapon. You perform the ritual over the
>   course of 1 hour, which can be done during a short rest. The weapon
>   must be within your reach throughout the ritual, at the conclusion of
>   which you touch the weapon and forge the bond.

Now from what I understand both warlocks with Book of ancient secrets and characters with the Ritual Caster Feat can learn ritual spells from other classes. Does this mean they could potentially learn Weapon Bond according to the rules?

On one hand, it seems that Weapon bond is a ritual which is learnt by a magic user subclass so I could see it as being classified as a ritual spell. On the other hand, it does not technically have it's own entry in the spell section of the rulebook and thus an no official spell level associated with it. The latter is somewhat important as Warlocks and Ritual casters can only learn new spells equal to or less than half their level. Obviously a DM could houserule a level associated with the ritual, but I want to know if there is an official answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## No

Weapon Bond is not a spell. The features you mention require you to learn a spell with the ritual tag (one example below). Not just any ritual.

> **Ritual Caster**
>
> ...ritual book holding two 1st-level spells of your choice [from a chosen class list]... the spells you choose must have the ritual tag